# Impedance questions for transformers

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

For any circuit using AC, we would use impedance to define the overall resistance of the circuit. But to calculate impedance, I have to determine which circuits are in parallel and which circuits are in series.

- In a transformer are the coils (primary and secondaries) in series or in parallel or do they share the same reactance? This is coils in one transformer.
- If a transformer can have coils in series and in parallel, what would each transformer look like?
- If I have multiple inductors in a transformer, would XLtotal(reactance of inductors) = XL1 + XL2 + XL3... in series and XLtotal = 1/XL1 + 1/XL2 + 1/XL3... in parallel or would I have to add different impedances for each coil in the transformer, in other words would the secondary coils be treated as a new circuit or would it be part of the XLtotal and be part of the total impedance that includes that primary coil?

Comment: You're combining way too many questions into one here. First, the equations you present mean nothing without context. What circuit are you referring to, and what characteristic of the circuit does each symbol (R, L, C, ...) refer to in each circuit (hint: you're using some symbols twice, but not with the same meaning)? Also, your 4th bullet point has been asked dozens of times before. Please search the site (or electronics SE) and read some of the previous answers, and then ask a more specific question if you still need clarification.

Comment: I have edited my post for better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

> In a transformer are the coils (primary and secondaries) in series or in parallel or do they share the same reactance? This is coils in one transformer.

Typically the primary and secondary are not connected to each other. If they were, that would eliminate one of the main benefits of using a transformer: galvanic isolation.

There is one type of transformer, called an *autotransformer* in which a single coil serves as both primary and secondary.

> If I have multiple inductors in a transformer, would XLtotal(reactance of inductors) = XL1 + XL2 + XL3... in series

No. Due to the magnetic coupling, the behavior is not so simple.

For example, if your transformer has two windings, with each winding having the same inductance, $L$, when considered individually, the inductance after connecting the two windings in series (if you connect them such that the current through the windings produces core flux in the same direction) will be $4L$.If you connect them in series such that the flux produced from the two windings is in opposite directions, the equivalent inductance of the combination will be approximately zero (but not quite zero, due to imperfect magnetic coupling).

> and XLtotal = 1/XL1 + 1/XL2 + 1/XL3... in parallel

For the case of identical windings, connecting them in parallel in fact doesn't change the equivalent inductance (again, assuming you pick the polarities so that the fluxes from the coils reinforce each other). That is, the equivalent inductance of two coupled windings with inductance $L$ in parallel with each other, is just $L$. This is because the total flux developed for a given total current is the same as if only one coil were connected.

> would the secondary coils be treated as a new circuit or would it be part of the XLtotal and be part of the total impedance that includes that primary coil?

You need to consider both the secondary coil inductance and the effect of the mutual inductance between the coils to determine the equivalent inductance when combining the windings.

Comment: How would you know if the secondary coil has the same or opposite current direction as the primary coil? Also, if the inductance is close to zero, that means the coils that share opposing current will be preferred (if I do not have a capacitor) since XL is that close to zero number.

Comment: @JuicyYellow, on a schematic, look at the dots on the coils. In a physical circuit you have to look at which way the coils are wrapped around the core. What's "preferred" depends on what circuit you are building.

Comment: The only thing I can think of for the coils to have opposing directions of current is by an 180 degree phase shift difference where +peak max of one coil is -peak max of the other coil. They would have to be phase adjusted, though i am not sure on how to make those adjustments.